Film set in two universes
I've been searching for the title of a certain film for quite a while now with no success, so I come here in case any of the stuff I remember rings a bell to someone.
So, I remember that this film is set in two universes, the one being our own and the other a Dystopian one tightly controlled by the government.   
I remember that towards the beginning of the film, a man with a completely white mask over his head strolls through a city (in the Dystopian universe) and then he enters a bar where after a while some people in uniform (I think it was mentioned that they were some sort of 'police') enter and proceed to capture him. A fight happens and the man manages to escape.  
I also remember that in the city there were lots of people preaching weird religions.  
I think the film is post 2000.  
The film is not a cartoon, it's a live-action film.
If I remember any more details I'll add them.

I found the film I was looking for, it was Franklyn:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0893402/

Do you mean Faq: Frequently Asked Questions? http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0449590/ 
From what I remember of it, it resembles your description of the movie ;)

No, unfortunately it isn't that one :\ Edit: Nevermind, I found it. It was Franklyn http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0893402/  Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me anyway :)

@ConstantineLoukas please post your finding as a separate answer and accept it :)

Well great that you found it anyways :D
